# Re install my Fedora

Tags: fedora

I found that my fedora was not working properly. I wanted to re-install the Fedora but my computer has a Window installed also(Dual-boot). I don't want to remove or affect the Window. What can I do? Can I just format the Block Devices? Or, are there any image that I can use to recover my Fedora without affecting the Window?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking backup of your all data first then try this step.

1. Try to change the first boot order from BIOS ,Fedora to Windows
2. Make flash-able Pen Drive of Fedora
3. Insert it and go to the installation section and configure partition manually
4. Just remove the previous Fedora partitions by selecting and clicking on minus sign below at the left corner
5. And make partitions of /boot,/,/boot/efi and swap and just click on install 
   6.After installation check Windows is working properly
6. Change boot order to Fedora from Bios menu

Answer (score 0):

backup needed system config files, boot from live or other cd, find your fedora partition, reformat fedora partition, exclude /home... Installer find your Windows system automatically and added in to GRUB boot menu...